# Add multiple constraints on Excel Solver

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

In excel solver,i need a variable to either be zero or lie between 50% of max to 100%. i.e it should not lie between 0 to 50% but can be zero. how to add a constraint like this?

Comment: Without knowing your situation it's very difficult to give a solution. I've just two idea: 1: if you have only one variable with this behaviour, then simply run solver twice with the two value / range and use the better results. 2: adjust your formulas so they consider attribute value 50 as it would be 0.

Comment: Something like "NOT(0% < a ≤ 50%)"?

Answer (score -1):

Add a dummy variable in another cell with a formula that returns a 1 when the primary variable is 0 or 0.5-1, and returns 0 any other time.

Then put a constraint on this dummy variable, so that it must be 1 in an accepted solution.

Comment: seems logical, but I'm afraid how solver can manage such a variable. Have you tested this approach already?

Comment: You are correct that solver doesn't like variables that suddenly switch state. But depending on you problem, it may still solve.